# Find indices of non-repeating slices of natural number given quantity and group length

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

perhaps you are already confused by the title. I have got an interesting problem, but it is beyond by knowledge. I urge for seeking help.

I will try my best to describe the question as clear as possible, I promise it's not very complex.

---

I have a set of natural numbers, in range of `n`, for instance:

```
[0, 1] : n = 2
[0, 1, 2] : n = 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] : n = 6
```

put the set of the natural numbers into groups with length `l`, the rule is that each number must be with any other any number **only** once, in other word **non-repeated**, which sequence does not matter.

for example:

```
# group [1, 2, 3] by a length of 2
[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3] 

# group [1, 2, 3, 4] by a length of 3
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]
```

The task is to represent sorted matrix by positional index of individual group, for instance:

```
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
# [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]
# 2 x 6
# [0 0 0 1 1 2]
# [1 2 3 2 3 3]


# [0, 1, 2, 3]
# [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]
# 3 x 4
# [0 0 0 1]
# [1 1 2 2]
# [2 3 3 3]


# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]
# 3 x 10
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2]
# [1 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 3 3]
# [2 3 4 3 4 4 3 4 4 4]
```

In other words,

```
# given 2 x 6, generate: 
# [0 0 0 1 1 2]
# [1 2 3 2 3 3]


# given 3 x 4, generate: 
# [0 0 0 1]
# [1 1 2 2]
# [2 3 3 3]


# given 4 x 8, generate: 
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2]
# [1 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 3 3]
# [2 3 4 3 4 4 3 4 4 4]
```

the performance of the algorithm will be largely increased if the index is evaluated inside of the iteration.

In detail, with known

- current iteration index as horizontal index of the outcome matrix
- group length `l`
- how many groups will be generated (gained by following algorithm)

to find:

- a list of numbers of length `l` represent current matrix composition.

```
# python 3.7
# how many groups will be generated
# is calculated by pascal triangle

import math


def factorial(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    val = 1
    for i in range(num):
        val *= i + 1
    return val


def reduce(row, col):
    return int(factorial(row) / (factorial(col) * factorial(row - col)))


def slicer(var, required):
    # get the length of tha passed in list, for example [0, 1, 2, 3] -> 4
    length = len(var)
    how_many_groups = reduce(length, required)
    for i in range(how_many_groups):
        # iteration
        pass
```

let's make it specific,

```
# 3 x 4: 
# [0 0 0 1]
# [1 1 2 2]
# [2 3 3 3]

# when iteration i is equal to 0, I want to find
# [0 1 2]

# when iteration i is equal to 1, I want to find
# [0 1 3]
```

Thanks very much for reading to the end. I am truly sorry if it has confused you.

Any help is appreciable.